# Programatically change selected option of a Dojo Form Select that is populated by label value pair object

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.mobile

I have a Dojo Form Select input box where I fill the options using a javascript data object having lable value pairs (example code to build such object below):

```
for loop {
  varStateValuePairs.push({
    label: <State ID>, 
    value: <State Name>
  });
}
dijit.byId("StateDDL").addOption(varStateValuePairs);
```

Now, I want to programmatically select a specific State within this Dojo Form Select.
I have tried the following:

```
dijit.byId("StateDDL").attr("value", String(5)); // 5 is the example value corresponding to the label-value pair I want to select
dijit.byId("StateDDL").attr("value", 5);
dojo.byId("StateDDL").value = 5;
dijit.byId("StateDDL").set("displayedValue", "Texas");
```

None of the above works. Where am I wrong? I have searched quite a lot and none of the solutions listed in other posts are working for me. I am running Dojo 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select.setValue()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/qauHX/2/

`value0` would be selected by default, we select `value2` manually.

```
var varStateValuePairs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  varStateValuePairs.push({
    label: "state"+i, 
    value: "value"+i
  });
}

require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/Select", "dojo/domReady!"], function (parser, registry) {
    parser.parse().then(function () {
        var widget = registry.byId("StateDDL");
        widget.addOption(varStateValuePairs);
        widget.setValue("value2");
    });
});
```

Comment: I see that your code is working fine on jsfiddle.net. I mirrored same code within mine but it does not work. All my other page works perfectly fine, no errors showing in Chrome developer tools. Only this part does not work. Matter of fact, I have other (statically updated) dojo form select objects where it all works fine.

Comment: I see, not sure what to say then other than maybe take a closer look at the differences between the jsfiddle and your code.

Comment: Your suggestion to " take a closer look at the differences between the jsfiddle and your code" helped. The only difference I could find is that my values were originally assigned as integer in the data object. I now changed it to String at the time of building the data object. That solved the problem. So, conclusion is that Dojo.form.select does not go well with integer values. We must use strings instead. Thanks for the help buddy.

Comment: That sounds like a good spot; One of those tricks that can keep you staring at the screen for hours! I'm sure that tip will come in handy.